# Ghostscript read permissions debugging in visual studio iisexpress

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ghostscript, iis-express

Hi All: I have a website that generates a single-page PDF using iTextSharp and converts it to JPG using Ghostscript.net (1.2.3) and latest 64-bit libraries.

The process works fine when the website is running on server2012r2, but if I try to run the project in Visual Studio/IIS Express on my Windows 10 Pro box, I get an error when trying to read the PDF using rasterizer.GetPage() method. My code is below. I added the two rasterizer CustomSwitches after googling for similar errors but the error is exactly the same.

```
    Public Shared Function genImgFromPDF(pdf As String) As String
    Dim desired_x_DPI As Integer = 300
    Dim desired_y_DPI As Integer = 300
    Dim src As String = String.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/pdfTempIDs/{0}"), pdf)
    Dim imgName As String = Left(pdf, InStrRev(pdf, ".") - 1) + ".jpg"
    Dim dest As String = String.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/jpgTempID/{0}"), imgName)

    Dim _installedVersion As GhostscriptVersionInfo = GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion(GhostscriptLicense.GPL, GhostscriptLicense.GPL)
    Dim _rasterizer As New Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer
    Try

        _rasterizer.Open(src, _installedVersion, True)
        Dim cnt As Integer = _rasterizer.PageCount
        _rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dNEWPDF=false")
        _rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-r300x300")
        Dim img As Image = _rasterizer.GetPage(300, cnt)
        img.Save(dest, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Return imgName
    Catch ex As Exception
        logging.insErr("tempID", "error generating JPG", ex.Message, "Autogenerated")

        Return "error"
    End Try
End Function
```

[image: Error trying to save image when it's "nothing" because the PDF was not read]

As I mentioned this code works in production, just not when I'm debugging in Visual Studio. I'm assuming it's a permissions error related to Ghostscript and not IIS Express, since I can generate and save the PDF successfully before passing the filename/path to Ghostscript. I'm using an absolute path (Server.MapPath) and passing that to ghostscript in the getPage() method, like "C:\development\VSprojects\project\pdfSrc\pdfname-20220928.pdf". Is this a permissions issue specific to GhostScript, or something else?

Comment: Have you forced the project to x64 bits? You can't use "any cpu" since you might get a running x32 instance. In fact prior to vs2022, you WILL in fact get a x32 bit process, and if you using the gs x64 library, then such codee will fail. So double check and force the project to x64 bits when you run + test on your local machine. Any CPU can't be used, or at least better stated should not be used.

Comment: @KJ using the current version of GhostscriptRasterizer (9.56.1), the "GetPage" method only accepts 2 parameters "dpi" and "pageNumber", so "_rasterizer.GetPage(300, cnt)"

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal --I thought this might be the answer, but I am running in x64 mode and I confirmed that it's the 64-bit dll installed.

Comment: @KJ I commented out the custom switches and the same result..."NullReferenceException" after GetPage. I will try to trap the GS call and update if I can figure out how to do it properly in VS2019. :(

Comment: This isn't 'Ghostscript' it's either Ghostscript.NET or Ghostscriptsharp. You would probably do better tagging the question with whichever of those you are using.